# Ember - How to set a controller for each item in CollectionView

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to display a list of views with it's respective controller in a CollectionView using ember.js

The problem is that the collectionView won't create a controller for each item.

This binjs illustrates more or less what i'm trying to accomplish: http://jsbin.com/uZapEWix/1/edit?html,js,output

Note that the buttons are not calling the action in the controller for the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in ember.

Refer to [Issue #4137](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4137#issuecomment-32242681)

Answer (score 0):

When you add child view to `CollectionView` child will have the same controller as `CollectionView`.

I see two solutions, one is to change approach and use regular view with bunch of `render` helpers to associate controller to child view or in your current implementation in child view template add render helper in order to add another view. Thanks to `render` helper associated controller will create.

Comment: It's a bug, see Issue #4137 -> https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4137#issuecomment-32242681